# How to detect iOS SMS capability (NOT text messaging in general)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm writing an app that optionally allows you to send an SMS to a list of users. The app currently detects whether the device allows the sending of text messages using MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() and only displays the "Send SMS" button when the result is true.

Today, one of my users complained that when he hit the button on his Wifi-only iPad, nothing happened. As it turns out, canSendText() also returns true if the iOS device has the iMessage capability turned on, even if SMS is not supported. Turning the iMessage capability off in the iOS setting properly disables the "Send SMS" button.

The problem with sending the message via iMessage is that some recipients will have iMessage turned on and thus will receive the text message. But for the recipients without iMessage (it may be turned off or they may not be using an Apple device in the first place), those messages will not arrive. (When the MFMessageComposeViewController eventually comes up, those addresses are marked in red. But my average user is not going to understand that this means the message will not delivered.)

Does anybody know of a reliable method that tests for SMS capability specifically, not just for text messages (SMS, iMessage and MMS) in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know devices with iOS 5+ will return `TRUE` for `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()` as they are capable of `iMessage`

So I assume you only need to send text if SIM card is installed on device.
But there is no way to detect if SIM card is installed on device. Still you can use workaround like :

```
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString *mobileCountryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode;
NSString *carrierName = carrier.carrierName;
NSString *isoCountryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
NSString *mobileNetworkCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode;

NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@", mobileCountryCode, carrierName, isoCountryCode, mobileNetworkCode);
```

Here, `carrierName` will return name when SIM card is present OR last use SIM card info. But others will be `null` if there is no SIM card installed.

Comment: It seems like that would work for the majority of cases. Thanks. However, I can imagine corner cases where this would not work. Such as a user who has a SIM which is expired, or whose plan does not allow for SMS messages (e.g. data only). Any idea if there's a way to tackle these cases too?

Comment: @WouterLiefting : I dont think it would be possible programatically. For expired SIM you can insert that SIM and run above code and check values. I haven't tested with expired SIM as I dont have one.